# How to use r.js in browser to reduce HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, web, requirejs, r.js

There are lot of examples for reducing HTTP requests using r.js but, all the examples are explained for node.js alone. I want to know whether we can implement r.js in a normal web application. If it is possible then how to do that?

Comment: You would run r.js as a pre-deployment step, then deploy the combined files to your server, and finally add some custom requireJS paths that kick in only in your deployed environment.

Comment: And yeah - you need node.js installed to run it.

Comment: Hi Adam thanks for the update. Curious to know that without node.js can't we do it?

Comment: no, not that I know of.  Installing node is pretty easy though, and baking up a script / bat file to use it also fairly easy.

Comment: Here's a sample from our bat file that does all our combining and compressing (compressing done with Google Closure) `node r.js -o optimize=none exclude=text,tasks/taskComponents baseUrl=../ paths.text=assets/js/text name=tasks/tasks out=../tasks/tasks-build-unminified.js`